# Celsius to fahrenheit android

Tags: java, android

```
public static int convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(Long celcious){
    return Math.round(celcious * 9/5 + 32);     
}
```

I am trying to set it to my TextField. I am not able to set the value in the `Text Field`, coz i am getting the NumberFormatException. **How can i send it with precision values.**

```
holder.textItem.setText(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(Long.parseLong(
              custom.getTemperature())));
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "32.2222222222222"

Comment: Seems you need `Double` or `double` here.

Comment: `Long` is a type of integer, so `"32.2222"` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answers about parsing as `float` etc, note that `setText` is overloaded. When it takes an int, it is a resource Id, so make a `string` and give it that:

Instead of:

```
holder.textItem.setText(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(...));
```

Do:

```
holder.textItem.setText(String.format("%d", convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(...)));
```

Or:

```
holder.textItem.setText(String.format("%d\x00B0 f", convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(...)));
```

Should give you "10° f" (untested)

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `float` to `long`

you could just use a casting

```
(long) custom.getTemperature()
```

However, if all you have is a String representing a floating point number, you may want to change your convert function, to receive a float instead.-

```
public static int convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celcious){
    return Math.round(celcious * 9.0f / 5.0f + 32);     
}
```

And pass

```
Float.parseFloat(custom.getTemperature())
```

Don't forget to divide `9.0f / 5.0f` instead of `9 / 5`, as the last one is an integer division and will always return 1.

Comment: Note that "Long.parseLong" is used to convert String to Long And  you Cannot cast from String to long by using (long)String

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 holder.textItem.setText(" "+convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(Float.parseFloat(
                  custom.getTemperature())));
```

and

```
public static int convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(Float celcious){
            return Math.round(celcious * 9/5 + 32);     
        }
```

Comment: Arun: i am getting this error. 04-17 17:51:08.901: E/AndroidRuntime(1087): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5a
04-17 17:51:08.901: E/AndroidRuntime(1087):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
04-17 17:51:08.901: E/AndroidRuntime(1087):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)

Comment: Make sure that you are assigning string resource to your view that are declared properly in values folder

Comment: My thought here is how come a type of int gets set into a TextField.

Comment: See my answer, you need to format the `int` returned as a `string`.